# How do I show that this fraction is smaller than 1?

Tags: limits, inequality

I have $a>b>0$ and $z = \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$

As $b\to a$ we have $z \to 1$ and as $b\to 0$ we have $z\to 0$. Is this sufficient to show that $z\lt 1$? If not how can I do it?

---

$$\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}\lt\frac{a-\sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}}{b}\lt\frac{a-\sqrt{(a-b)(a-b)}}{b}\lt1$$

Comment: The first $<$ should be a $=$. You should evaluate $\sqrt{(a-b)(a-b)}$ and then reduce the fraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

$$\frac{a-\sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}}{b} < \frac{a-\sqrt{(a-b)(a-b)}}{b} $$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
a-b & < a+b\\
\sqrt{a-b} & < \sqrt{a+b}\\
a-b & < \sqrt{a^2-b^2}\\
a- \sqrt{a^2-b^2} & < b\\
\frac{a- \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}& < 1.
\end{align}